# Strange behavior of CoreData's '-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1' option

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

## Fully reproduce code:

https://github.com/kenmaz/CoreDataVioration/tree/master

## Summary

I have two CoreData Entites, EntityA and EntityB.

And NSManagedObjectContext hierarchy is here:

```
- RootSaving Context ( private queue) 
 - Main Context ( main queue )
 - Private Context (private queue)
```

In my sample code, execute three code blocks in parallel.

1. In private context, insert and save EntityA record
2. In main context, fetch EntityB record
3. in main context, fetch EntityA record

I think #2 and #3 run in serial in actualy because use main queue and perofmBlock: method.

psudo code:

```
[privateContext performBlock:^{
    NSEntityDescription* entADesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityA" inManagedObjectContext:privateContext];
    EntityA* entA = [[EntityA alloc] initWithEntity:entADesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:privateContext];
    entA.foo = @"aaa";

    [privateContext save:&error];

    NSManagedObjectContext* parentContext = privateContext.parentContext;
    [parentContext performBlock:^{
        [parentContext save:&error];
    }];
}];

//fetch EntityB (asyn on main context)    
[mainContext performBlock:^{
    NSFetchRequest* req = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"EntityB"];
    NSArray* results = [mainContext executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];
}];

//fetch EntityA (asyn on main context)
[mainContext performBlock:^{
    NSFetchRequest* req = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"EntityA"];
    req.fetchBatchSize = 20; // If comment out this line, No break
    req.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"foo = %@", @"wwww"]; // If comment out this line, No break
    NSArray* results = [mainContext executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];  // ******* BREAK with __Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor__ !!!!! ********
}];
```

Xcode stop in #3 code block with `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION.`

I can see "**Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor**" in stack trace, so I think this breaks cuased by CoreData's ConcurrencyDebug option.

[image]

If you turn off ConcurrencyDebug option, this code works fine.

## Question

Why ConcurrencyDebug option stops my code ?

## Steps to Reproduce:

1. Clone sample code from: 
   https://github.com/kenmaz/CoreDataVioration/tree/master
2. Open CoreDataViolationCrash.xcodeproj with Xcode
3. Edit Scheme > Run > Argument Passed on Launch >
4. Add "-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1"
5. Run with simulator (cmd+R)
6. Press 'button' button once or twice on main screen.
7. Xcode stop the execution with exception.

## Environment

- iOS 9.3.2
- Xcode 7.3 (7D175)
- Mac OSX 10.11.4
- Simulator: iPhone6s
- Actual device: iPhone6

## Open Radar

I reported this behavior as bug. https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4944086339420160

Comment: your described hierarchy misrepresents the code as the private context is a child of saving not main